# Scroll to top when changing pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a pagination component (React). I need the scroll to be moved to the top when changing pages. Can someone help me?

```
const MAX_BTN = 9;
const MAX_BTN_LEFT = (MAX_BTN - 1) / 2;

const Pagination = ({items, limit = 20, page, setPage}) => {
  const pages = items !== null && Math.ceil(items.total_results / limit);
  const startBtn = Math.max(page - MAX_BTN_LEFT, 1);

  return (
    <ul className="pagination">
      {Array(Math.min(MAX_BTN, pages)).fill()
        .map((_, i) => i + startBtn)
        .map(value => (
          <li key={value}>
            <button onClick={() => setPage(value)}>{value}</button>
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: Are you using React Router?

Comment: @Unmitigated yes. how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return to the top with a function:

```
  const handlePageChange = value => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    setPage(value);
  }
```

And calling it in your button:

```
  ...
  <li key={value}>
    <button onClick={() => handlePageChange(value)}>{value}</button>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it solved my problem. I made changes to the code to move the scroll bar more smoothly. Here is the code for those who need it:  window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth', 
    });

Answer (score 1):

call the browser `window` object with below method `scrollTo` when you click on the Link

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to handle this is by creating a single `ref` for the top-most part of your app. Then pass the ref into a hook which handles scrolling to the top of the page when the pathname changes.

Here's a simple hook I use (type definitions can be cleaned up):

**useScrollToTop.ts**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';

const useScrollToTop = (ref: any) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  // ensure pages scroll to top
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref?.current) {
      ref.current.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }, [ref?.current, location.pathname]);

  return null;
};

export default useScrollToTop;
```

Now at the top of your app's very first element add the reference.

**App.js**: (or whatever component)

`import useScrollToTop from './useScrollToTop';`

Then create a new empty ref:

`const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);`

Pass the ref into the hook:

`useScrollToTop(ref)`

Define the ref on the top-most part of your app (example inner components):

```
return (
  <div ref={ref}>
    <Header />
    <Navigation />
    <Content />
    <Footer ?>
  </div>
);
```

Now anytime the path changes, your end-user will scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: I liked your answer. It works on routes, but it doesn't work when I use my Pagination component